# Vectorized approach to creating a matrix with 1s in indices given by a column vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, multilabel-classification

Let's say I'm given a `1000x1` column vector of with values ranging from 1-10. Now I want to turn this into a `1000x10` matrix, where for each row there is a 1 in the column given by the value in the column vector. I have a correct implementation below, but is there an elegant way to do this without a `for` loop?

```
ymat = zeros(1000, 10);
y = randi([1,10],1000,1);
for i=1:1000
    ind = y(i);
    ymat(i,ind)=1;
end
```

Comment: The above duplicate answers your problem.  Simply transpose the result to get what you need, or reverse the row and column indices in the answers without transposing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can access any subset of the entries in ymat all at once using the "[linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/)" of those entries. Since we already have y that contains the column coordinates, and the row coordinates are simply 1:100, We can easily obtain their linear index value with `sub2ind`, and then set all the indexed values to 1 in `ymat`:

```
ymat(sub2ind([1000 10], (1:1000)', y)) = 1
```

However note that `ymat` with the proper size must be created before hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have set of column indices and corresponding row index should be `1:1000`.

There are two options to generate matrix from this.

1. accumarray
2. sparse

acccumarray will generate **full** matrix and sparse will generate **sparse** matrix.

In your case, the resulting matrix has density of 10% which can be considered as sparse matrix.

```
% Full matrix using accumarray
ymat = accumarray([(1:1000).', y], ones(1000,1), [1000, 10]);

% Sparse matrix using sparse
ymat = sparse(1:1000, y, ones(1000,1), 1000, 10, 1000);
```

## Computation time

I run the code with `y = 1000 x 1` and `y = 10000 x 1`.

1. y = 1000 x 1

[image: size of <code>y</code> is <code>1000 x 1</code>]

2. y = 10000 x 1

[image: size of <code>y</code> is <code>10000 x 1</code>]

I added the code suggested by @transversality condition.

It turns out that `accumarray` is the fastest and `sparse` is the slowest.

`accumarray` shows better performance for small size, but the gap between `accumarray` and `bsxfun(@eq)` gets smaller as we increase the size of array.

Comment: A possible optimization with `sparse` is that you don't need the `ones` vector to declare all of the non-zero entries as 1.  A special case with `sparse` is if every non-zero value in the matrix is equal to the same value, you only have to specify a single constant to reflect all of these values.  Therefore, just do `ymat = sparse(1:1000, y, 1, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use `repmat` and `bsxfun`. E.g.,

```
bsxfun(@eq,repmat(1:10,numel(y),1),repmat(y,1,10))
```

Answer:

```
 ...
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0

>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`ind2vec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/ind2vec.html) function:

```
ymat=full(ind2vec(y.').')
```